# Populate select boxes in php

Tags: php

I am learning php and have a form on one page. When you press the submit button (using `$_GET`) it goes to a new page with the rest of the form.

I am geting the number of adults in a select box.

How can I `$_GET` the values and put it into the select option so it is populated?

Comment: please show your piece of form from your first page, and the html code for `select` on second page.

Comment: So what have you tried so far. Post code which didnt work as you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a form that posts to self.

When building the option list, we check the value against the user supplied one, if they match, add the attribute 'selected'.

```
<?php

$options = array('3', '4', '5');
$adults  = null;
$error   = null;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $adults = isset($_POST['adults']) ? $_POST['adults'] : null;

    // Check the user supplied valid number.
    if(in_array($adults, $options)) {
        echo 'Valid post.';
        // Your processing.
    } else {
        $error = 'Invalid option for adult.';
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head><title>Select list form</title></head>
<body>
<?php if($error) echo $error; ?>
<form method="POST">
    Number of adults:<br />
    <select name="adults">
    <?php foreach($options as $number) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $number; ?>"
            <?php echo $number == $adults ? 'selected' : ''; ?>
        >
            <?php echo $number; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted you can get the values send by $_GET['variable name'];

If your select is with name adult_number you can check it for the select like this

```
<select name="x">
<?php
$adult_number = $_GET['adult_number'];
for($i=0; $i<10; $i+=1)
{
    $selected = ($adult_number == $i ? 'selected' : '');
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'" '.$selected.' />';
}
?>
```

This will check if the submitted amount is equal to $i(from 1 to 10 for example) and if it is equal it will select this option of the select.

Answer (score -1):

Get the values and store it in array, after that you make a loop to create the options of your select.
If you use framework like symfony, you can do that more cleanest.